# How to extract a sub-part of a library with maven?

Tags: java, maven, extract

In my pom.xml file, I declare a dependency with the apache library : commons.math3-3.6.1.jar (21 subdirectories. The size of this library is about 2162Ko).
From my point of view, this library is heavy for my use. I would like to extract only
the part I need: org.apache.commons.math3.ode.
I've read a lot of explanations, but I haven't found anything that would help me.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you for your help.
RLB

For information: currently, I create the .jar file with the command :
mvn package assembly:single.
This jar file has a size of 2.2 MB, which includes the commons.math3 library and another one.
With the command :
mvn package,
the generated jar file is 8Kb in size. It includes only my own code.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.rlb</groupId>
<artifactId>FlyingBall</artifactId>
<version> 0 </version>
<name>FlyingBallCode</name>
<description>My description </description>

<properties>  
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.siani.javafmi</groupId>
        <artifactId>fmu-framework</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- RLB : Exclude the class which contain the main function, before jar creation. -->
                    <exclude>siani/javafmi/FlyingBallMain.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First of all, why is it a problem? Very little space or bandwidth? Second, there are corner cases where you cannot decide programmatically which classes are needed - only way to be sure you have what you need is through heavy testing.

Comment: I would also ask what is really the problem here? Also why using `mvn package assembly:single.` to create a jar I suppose using jar-with-dependencies. The other important part is: Does not exist a more recent version of math lib because this one is of 2016?

Comment: Comment for Thorbjørn : Thanks for your comment. Yes, it is for space and speed reasons and because I need to create a lot of small libraries that include this commons.math3 library, for simulation.

In my code, I specify which class I need. However, as you suggested, I prefer to test my approach before I continue to develop other small libraries for simulation.

On the Apache site, the most recent commons.math3 library is version 3.6.1

Comment: Comment for khmarbaise: Thanks for your comment. I used mvn package assembly :single command because I don't know what other command to use. I don't know how to make the link between the assembly and the output of the package execution command. Running this command gives me the expected result. I'm new to using Maven. :- ))

Comment: You can tag a person using `@user` with tab-completion.  The way Java works, large jar files only take space on disk, only classes needed are loaded into memory.  So, unless you have an actual problem with this, I would suggest saving it for later and solve other stuff first.

Comment: Comment for Thorbjørn : Thanks for your comment. You said that java load into memory only needed class. You give me an answer that meets my needs. I'm happy about that, so I'll stop looking for the way to extract a part of the commons.math3 library. In you comment, you wrote that it could be possible to use a tag @user. My question: In which file should this tag be placed and where?